# Getting value of input and passing along through querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to get the value of text typed by a user in an input box but the problem is that instead of getting the value which the user has typed, I get the preset value of the input which is 'undefined'.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="userInput" value="" name="title" 
       placeholder="Enter the name here" required="required"/>
<input type="button" id="text_value" value="Set Input"/>
   <!-- I have this button here because I think maybe 
    I should have a button to change default value but
    I don't know the javascript to do this -->
```

**Javascript**

```
// Gets input value id 

    var theuserInput = $("#userInput").val();
```

The reason I haven't shown query string code is because the input value is passed along in the url but the problem is that the default input value 'undefined' is passed instead of actual user input.

Any solutions?

**ADDITIONAL CODE**

Ok so here is the querystring, when you click the 'pass' button the input is passed along in querystring:

```
$('.pass').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://lala.com/passing.php?input=' + theuserInput + '';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried completely ridding the `value=""` ?

Comment: Are you getting `undefined` or a empty string (`""`)?

Comment: add your full js code.

Comment: I get undefined, if i set the value="hi" I get hi as well. And I have tried ridding the value="" and still get same error

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon Where do you get undefined? In console? Get rid of the `.this` and make sure you run the code when the button is clicked. You need to provide more code.

Comment: Updated the question and will keep updating for more, thanks!

Comment: What's the pass button? And when are you defining `theuserInput`?

Comment: pass button is just a html button with class "pass". And I'm defining theuserInput here: `var theuserInput = $("#userInput").val();`

Comment: It seems as if you need a way to refresh your input box after a user types inside so the input box is updated and preset to their input.

Comment: I get undefined on the url link when i click 'passing'.

Comment: I mean are you defining `theuserInput` within the click handler for the button `text_value` or somewhere else? If somewhere else, where exactly? If you are doing it on page load, the value is definitely going to be undefined. You need to make sure you are defining the variable when there actually is some text in the box. Or do you want a method of updating the variable whenever something is entered in the box? Please reply by using `@ṧнʊß` :)

Comment: I'd like a method of updating the variable whenever something is entered in the box :)

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/shub01/6qew4vzv/2/) fiddle

Comment: Can you provide more code please?

Comment: I've provided all code & @ṧнʊß how can I  incorporate the .change function in my js code?

Comment: It depends *where you've currently defined `theuserInput`*!! What surrounds the line where you've defined it??

Comment: All the code is provided in my question, and I can't really define the userInput within my click  considering I'm trying to pass it on a querystring. Thanks though

Comment: Ok, taking a stab here, but remove the `var theuserInput = $("#userInput").val();` *wherever* you've put it currently. Then, paste the code from the fiddle at the top of your document. It should work.

Comment: Doesn't work, the button is just highlighted.

Comment: What do you mean highlighted? Could you take a screenshot of the output? And possibly your current code?

Comment: Ok how about you make the 'set input' button reload the page/div after a user has typed and have the pass button disabled. Then on page reload, enable pass button.

Comment: @StackOverQuestions You don't need page reload for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('.pass').click(function() {
    var theuserInput = $("#userInput").val();
    window.location.href = 'http://lala.com/passing.php?input=' + theuserInput + '';
    return false;
});
```

The `this` is removed before the call to the `val()` method.

The reason why you get `undefined` is because `theuserInput` is not defined inside the anonymous function **scope** passed to `#click` method. The JS engine tries to find `theuserInput` inside the "englobing" scopes recursively until reaching the global scope or finding `theuserInput` value in one of the successive "englobing" scopes. Since, the variable `theuserInput` can't be found in any scope, it is affected the default value `undefined`.

- [DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/snn1w1mv/1/)
- [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6qew4vzv/)

Comment: This code *does* work, provided there's not anything else wrong.  I think you need to provide more code in your question.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qew4vzv/). It does work.

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready(...)`? ( http://api.jquery.com/ready/ .) If not, it will try to run your code before the page has loaded, and fail to find the `.pass` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theuserInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the problem is that the input's default value is not being updated.

Comment: That appears to be another way of stating `var theuserInput = $("#userInput").val();` but without jquery - it adds nothing.